# Replace entire body element (together with its attributes, such as classes and id)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I'm performing an AJAX call to replace my page's content. Unfortunately this preserves my entire `body` element with its old classes, which messes up my page's style.

I'm using someone else's code which I don't entirely understand:

```
function loadNewContent(url, bool) {
    url = ('' == url) ? window.location.pathname : url;
    var newSection = 'cd-'+url.replace('.html', '');
    var section = $('<div class="cd-main-content '+newSection+'"></div>');

    section.load(url+' .cd-main-content > *', function(event){
        // load new content and replace <main> content with the new one
        $('main').html(section);
        //if browser doesn't support CSS transitions - dont wait for the end of transitions
        var delay = ( transitionsSupported() ) ? 1200 : 0;
        setTimeout(function(){
            //wait for the end of the transition on the loading bar before revealing the new content
            ( section.hasClass('cd-about') ) ? $('body').addClass('cd-about') : $('body').removeClass('cd-about');
            $('body').removeClass('page-is-changing');
            $('.cd-loading-bar').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
                isAnimating = false;
                $('.cd-loading-bar').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
            });

            if( !transitionsSupported() ) isAnimating = false;
        }, delay);

        if(url!=window.location && bool){
            //add the new page to the window.history
            //if the new page was triggered by a 'popstate' event, don't add it
            window.history.pushState({path: url},'',url);
        }
    });
}
```

Is it possible to modify this piece of code, so that it will completely destroy the old `body` element and replace it with the new one? Or at least substitute the old `class` body attribute with the new one's?

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be calling (and therefore replacing) the 'main' section of your website, which is not the same as the body.

```
$('main').html(section);
```

I'd say if you were to replace `main` with `body` that should make a difference.

Comment: Tijmen that isn't quite working. If I only change `main` to `body` in this line, then the old body will get replaced, true, but I'm not getting the new `body` anywhere. And my page breaks.

Comment: hm, true. I need to go out for a bit now, but when I get back I'll look into it  further.